# Is looking up a table with precomputed values an O(1) algorithm?

Tags: java, c, algorithm, functional-programming

Consider any algorithm function

```
f(x0,x1,...xn).
```

If the output for each combination of input arguments was precomputed into a multidimensional array with n dimensions, could the algorithm that simply lookups the solution for a given call to the function in the array be considered a O(1) algorithm? Like

```
 f (x0,x1,..xn) { 
 return array[x0][x1]...[xn]; 
 }
```

Comment: How is it related with functional programming ?

Comment: You should precise what has to be taken in account to calculate the complexity here. Data size ? Number of parameters ? Big-oh notation makes no sense if you don't define a "unit" to measure the complexity.

Answer (score 2):

It would be O(n), not O(1), since you have to lookup `n+1` array indices in order to find the result.

Comment: It would be n O(1) ops, which is O(1)

Comment: @James not if `n` is the number of arguments of the function - in that case it is O(n).

Comment: How would it be O(1)? In order to find the location in the array, you have to do a lookup that takes into account the `n+1` indices - x0, x1, ... xn.

Comment: The number of arguments of a function is constant. I mean, yeah, you can express the complexity in terms of the number of arguments, but this is almost always misleading since the number of arguments is small and constant and not an interesting variable. -1 because, although not technically incorrect, this answer is not *useful*.

Comment: @delnan Well, the complexity is O(n) based on the definition of `n` in the question. As to whether or not that `n` can be considered as constant, that's a different question.

Comment: It's not clear from the question whether n is a variable as in something that changes and should influence the analysis, or a variable as in a placeholder for some constant that we don't feel like pinning down at this point. See my answer for elaboration. I'm not saying O(n) is wrong, I'm saying it's not the only valid answer and in fact possibly a misleading answer.

Comment: @mafso : `And the question clearly asks for the complexity depending on n.`. I don't think so. I think the OP wants to know how much he can reduce the complexity of his algorithm by storing the results of the first execution and then only performing lookups. As I understand it, what's important here is the complexity of the algorithm, but we have no information at all about it. It would be great the OP provides more information as requested...

Comment: @Dici Yes, but... with a constant **n** this question makes even less sense to me. But we really should wait until OP clarifies, I think we agree which answer fits which interpretation of the question, but looking at the answers, it's quite unclear what the question is...

Answer (score 1):

If the number of dimensions is variable, for example because your algorithm is dimension-agnostic and applications will use a wildly varying number of dimensions, then it's accurate to state the complexity as O(n) where n is the dimensionality (but typically n refers to the length of the input, d or k would be a more customary variable name). For example, the dimensionality can be a variable in algorithms for integrating or optimizing functions in k-dimensional spaces. Monte Carlo integration has a convergence rate of sqrt(k), for example.

However, usually n will be a small constant and only formally be a variable because we're given an algorithm *template*, so different algorithms following the same general scheme may use different (but constant) values in its place. Then it isn't an interesting variable and it would be more correct and useful to give the complexity as O(1) w.r.t. whatever other variable you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

A table lookup is algoritmically an `O(1)` operation because no matter the size the lookup will be performed in constant time.

`n` here is a poorly selected metric since `n` is really the number of variables that has to be read and applied to the array. Even though the operation can be reduced to an execution of `O(1)` the number of lookups are still `n` (actually `n+1` with a `0` based index)  which thus becomes `O(n)`. So due to the unfortunate choice of `n` it doesn't practically mean anything.

Comment: Hm, aren't there `n` constant time lookups according to the question?

Comment: Yes, I've reworded to more clearly answer the complete question

Comment: But with arrays you don't have to do n lookups, all you have to do, and you hope the compiler will do for you, one offset calculation and so one lookup. Maybe I'm still hungover

Comment: @James, Yes and no. The unit of measure is poorly defined. I'm afraid both answers `O(1)` and `O(n)` are equally correct/wrong for that reason. Still we try to avoid compiler optimizations, because what happens if `n` is a million?

Comment: @James: No matter what the compiler does, it has to read each variable at least once.

Comment: n cannot be a million at runtime if it was 10 at compile time. The choice of the letter n tricks us into believing it would vary. That produces the confusion of two contradicting answers being right and wrong at the same time. :-)

Comment: @SimonFischer, agreed!

Comment: Maybe mention time/space tradeoff, and that both complexities must be considered.

Comment: @Simon Fischer: in a theoretical analysis, you do allow n to take any value, which means that if n is a million, you did precompute an array with a million dimensions; and you can change n freely, recomputing the array accordingly. In this sense, array access takes O(n) operations. The truth is that in practice n is bounded, which makes it O(1), and asymptotic analysis is irrelevant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I guess we all understand asymptotic analysis but: The OP's algorithm was for a constant size problem. In that case we can consider the table a part of the algorithm. When we extend to arbitrary n by considering a table with variable dimensionality, we can no longer assume it is precomputed - it would take unlimited time. Hence we have to take initialization of the table into consideration of the runtime analysis, making it much more than O(n). BTW the fact that in practice n is bounded is not an argument why asymptotic analysis is irrelevant and that was not what I wanted to say.

Comment: @Simon Fischer: nope. In the question there is no mention of fixed n. The rationale behind preprocessing/query analysis is that you amortize the preprocessing time on an infinite number of queries, and only the query time matters (or put another way, preprocessing time is an independent aspect of the analysis). And yes, such an analysis presumes that the tables are available for all n's at no cost.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, there is: The function has n parameters, and the array is n-dimensional. No way to vary n (as the question is formulated - of course we could generalize as several answers are saying, including mine). For fixed n it also makes sense to assume the table is available at no cost as you say - it can be considered part of the algorithm. But as soon as n varies, of course you have to take that into consideration of your amortized analysis. I don't think the two of us should be arguing like this though - I guess we both understand this well enough and it won't help the OP a lot :-)

Comment: @Simon Fischer: I want the OP to clearly understand that 1) when n is unbounded, array accesses do cost O(n) time, not O(1); and 2) situations such that n is unbounded are of little relevance in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful not to confuse yourself. When we say an algorithm has time complexity *O(f(n))*, then *n* denotes the size of the input. In your case, however, the input size is always the same, confusingly also named *n*, but it would be better to call it *c* because it does not vary. Thus, you have actually defined an algorithm for a finite problem in which it is pointless to talk about time complexity. The computation time is always the same.

If your question is about a family of algorithms, then in fact the time for the lookup will be *Theta(n)* because you break this down into *n* lookups, but the time for initializing the lookup table will be *Theta(D^n * g(n))* if *D* is the number of values that the *x_i* can take on and *g(n)* is the complexity of precomputing the value.

Answer (score 0):

since you have mentioned this, **If the output for each combination of input arguments was precomputed into a multidimensional array with n dimensions.**

it is surely O(1). that is because you have a limited number of combinations before you call the function f() (since before calling the function f() all the combinations have to be calculated and saved in that multidimensional array). so what you just have to do is access the array for a particular combination of input.

Note, the complexity of this would be O(1) since we are considering the access time of an array to be O(1). if one argues that to access that array, it needs to add the indices to the base address (like a[i] = *(a + i) ), then since there will be n number of additions for n dimensions. the accessing time becomes O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, yes, array access takes `O(n)` time for `n` dimensions, when `n` is unbounded.

Practically speaking, `n` is never unbounded so that `n` is `O(1)`, and so is the access time.

Note that precomputation of the array takes time and storage exponential in `n` (at least `2^n` elements), so that situations with `n` really being unbounded do not arise, and asymptotic analysis on the number of dimensions is of little use.

The C standard recommends to support up to 256 dimensions; no computer on earth could store such an array. I don't think I ever exceeded `n=10`.

When array accesses follow a simple pattern, such as travelling across a single dimension, smart optimizers take this into account, resulting in `O(n + k)` access time for `k` accesses instead of `O(nk)`, i.e. `O(1)` instead of `O(n)` per access when `k>n`. (Both in theory and in practice.)

Answer (score -3):

the order should be O(n), however you may reduce it to lograthmic by using binary search.(In the best case scenario you can have a o(1) complexity)

Comment: I'm curious about how you could use binary search here. First, it only applies to sorted arrays, then, it has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: there are two options, either you can sort the algorithm using merge sort, which would cost you logN time then apply binary search which would be also cost logN time, so you have a net order(logN).  i think its better to change your data structure from array to bst.

Comment: Sort an algorithm ? You can sort data but not an algorithm. Plus, we don't even know if the output of the algorithm defines a comparison operation. Your answer is off-topic. Plus, merge sort complexity is not O(log(N)) but O(N log(N).

Comment: I'm sorry, but nothing you wrote makes any sense to me.

Comment: @Dici i mean to say sort the array/table. it was a typo. The best way is to change the data structure, use bst instead of tables